# JAVA blackjack game. String inside of array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple text base blackjack game. I was wondering how I would go about putting a string inside of an array, or having a String array and assign them values outside the array. if that makes sense. below is the code that I have for it;

```
int deck[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Jack,Queen,King,Ace};
```

obviously this won't work because the array is for an integer. Possibly a string array then assign numbers as stated before? have a great day!

Comment: If you must - `String deck[] = { "2",... }`

Comment: Why don't you create Card class with rank, suite ,name  etc. You will probably going to need all of them later anyway. Then you can keep those cards object in deck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Enum`:

```
public enum Rank {
    DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, 
    NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE;
}
```

You can add a value if necessary.

Then your array is of type `Rank[]`

Comment: And then you can do the same for the Suits, etc. `public Enum Suits { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES; }`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will have to have a read up on Enum. I understand how and why it would work, but still a little hazy on how I would implement. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ENUM for the values, like Two, Three...Jack, Queen, King.

```
public enum CardValue {
  Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace;
}
```

If you really want ints and Strings in an array, you could use Polymorphism like so:

```
Object[] deck = new Object[13];
deck[0] = (Object)new Integer(2);
...
deck[12] = (Object)new String("Ace");
```

You would have to cast everything back to the correct type too when you access it.

```
String card = (String)deck[12];
int anotherCard = (Integer)deck[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

The right way to do this is to make an enumeration, to this you can assign it's value with which you can calculate your game.